# Black Screen in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

Today I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 using Vmware. The problem is that when I turn on the virtual Machine (Ubuntu 14.04) then it takes me to the console not the GUI , I searched through Google and found it that is it possible problem with the graphics driver , I tried to update all drivers using command line still no success. I tried the recovery mode but same issue, I have also tried "nomoddset" but still no success, I have tried almost all solutions that are given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Sorry I cant add comments due to low reputation otherwise I would have comment there :)

### My Laptop Config:

DELL Studio 1558

Core i3

Intel HD Graphics

4Gb RAM

Comment: If you're at cmdline=console, I know that it's a bit stupid, but it can(/should) help you. Did you tried`startx`?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the desktop version and not the server version? Where exactly did you download the ISO from? Have you installed vmware-tools inside your ubuntu? How did you install ubuntu? Did you use VMware's easy-install?

Comment: @hoschiCZ: Thanks I tried startx Its showing me desktop but it is too laggy , I think I need to update/install my graphics driver fro ubuntu , Can you please help me with that as I didn't it in updates 

Jobin: Yes Desktop version, Now Installed v13 still same problem, I downloaded it from UBUNTU website , I installed Vmware on my Windows 7 and then I used easy install to install Ubuntu

Comment: VMWare is a company, which software are you using Player, Workstation, Fusion, etc?

Comment: @Jobin: Sorry , VMWare workstation v7